# React Native: How to make a view stick on screen while the screen changes?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, uitoolbar, react-navigation

I'm building a podcasting app with react native and I would like to implement the mini player you see at bottom of screen in most podcasting/music apps. See image below. I want to make the mini player stick no matter which screen you navigate to. Any idea how to implement this in react native? I'm using react navigation as the main navigator right now https://reactnavigation.org/.

[image]

Comment: Have u solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is use the magic of [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Think about your app as combination of two major screens.
1) The part with header, navigation menus and the playlist (inside  etc.)
2) The player

Try this layout

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <View style={styles.firstBox}>
        1)
    </View>
    <View style={styles.secondBox}>
        2)
    </View>
</View>
```

Now all you have to do is assign proper styles

```
const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    firstBox: {
        flex: 8
    },
    secondBox: {
        flex: 2
    }
}
```

This is enough for the basic structure. You can design accordingly.

Comment: Shashank, thanks for your response. But the mini player should only show up when the user taps on the "play" button. If there's nothing playing, firstBox should take up the whole screen. How would you implement that?

Comment: This can be done be making the main screen i.e. the one containing the playlist all the space ie. flex: 1 and make the player position: 'absolute'.
by making player absolute you can place it anywhere you want and the bottom position can be set using Dimensions.get('window').height - (size_of_player). If the project is open source and you can share the code with me I can help you better.

Comment: Can you check this question please?https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/fky3o0/how_to_add_a_fixed_bottom_player/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share